# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occurs on Spring Boot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I've been using WebFlux for a few months and this is the first time I've seen **NoClassDefFoundError** exception. I don't think I can reproduce the exception.... So I would like to share my case and ask for your opinion.

First, here's **build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = '(edited)'
version = '1'
sourceCompatibility = '15'
targetCompatibility = '15'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

def aws = '1.11.903'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre'
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:${aws}"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2:${aws}"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:${aws}"
    implementation 'org.mybatis.dynamic-sql:mybatis-dynamic-sql:1.3.0'

    // Managed by SpringBoot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my **build environment** is...

- Amazon Linux 2
- JDK : Amazon Corretto-15.0.2.7.1
- Gradle : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
- Build command is simply `./gradlew bootJar`

**Running environment** is...

- Docker on Amazon Linux 2
- Docker image : amazoncorretto:16
- Run command is

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address="*:(edited)" \
    -server \
    --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED \
    -Xmx300m \
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=logs/heap_dump \
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions \
    -XX:+UseG1GC \
    -Xlog:gc:logs/gc.log \
    -Xlog:gc+heap=debug \
    -verbosegc \
    -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp \
    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.client.encoding=UTF-8 -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 \
    -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar app.jar 2>&1
```

And finally here's the app **log**...

```
2021-11-23 23:59:59.229 D [reactor-http-epoll-3] [HttpWebHandlerAdapter] [99936588-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):15792] HTTP GET "/"
2021-11-23 23:59:59.230 D [reactor-http-epoll-3] [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] [99936588-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):15792] Mapped to xxx(edited).NoSessionAction#default404()
2021-11-23 23:59:59.230 D [reactor-http-epoll-3] [HttpWebHandlerAdapter] [99936588-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):15792] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND


2021-11-24 00:00:00.731 W [reactor-http-epoll-3] [SingleThreadEventExecutor] Unexpected exception from an event executor: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/socket/ChannelInputShutdownReadComplete
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.shutdownInput(AbstractEpollChannel.java:526)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:733)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:821)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelInputShutdownReadComplete
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 9 common frames omitted


2021-11-24 00:00:06.762 D [reactor-http-epoll-4] [HttpWebHandlerAdapter] [91e1a7c5-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):49428] HTTP GET "/"
2021-11-24 00:00:06.762 D [reactor-http-epoll-4] [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] [91e1a7c5-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):49428] Mapped to xxx(edited).NoSessionAction#default404()
2021-11-24 00:00:06.762 D [reactor-http-epoll-4] [HttpWebHandlerAdapter] [91e1a7c5-1, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):49428] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND


(omitted)


2021-11-24 00:52:36.450 W [reactor-http-epoll-1] [AbstractChannel] Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop: [id: 0xf9a90949, L:/(IPv4):50006 - R:/(IPv4):47044]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:923)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:350)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:343)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:825)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:815)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:483)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.register(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:86)
    at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$Acceptor.channelRead(ServerTransport.java:381)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollServerChannel$EpollServerSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollServerChannel.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I unzipped the jar files, and I found there was **ChannelInputShutdownReadComplete.class** in "BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-4.1.70.Final/io/netty/channel/socket" well.

So my concerns are...

1. Why **org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader** could not load **ChannelInputShutdownReadComplete** class?
2. How would I catch the exception and let the app shutdown gracefully?

I'm using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...) but this caught nothing :(

3. How can I diagnose my case more deeply?

Comment: most likely something is pulling in something older than you expect it too. for instance `org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0` could be pulling in spring 2.2.0 instead of 2.6.0 that you have stated at the top. You can debug dependencies and look at what is actually pulled in by reading here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Toerktumlare.　Here's the build scan report [https://scans.gradle.com/s/laee7sufbshtu](https://scans.gradle.com/s/laee7sufbshtu).　Latest version(2.2.0) of `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` has dependencies with `spring-boot-starter:2.5.0` and `spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.5.0`. But the report says those with `2.6.0-SNAPSHOT` were taken ─ which I intended.

Comment: spring does not have a 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT its currently in full release, could you try hard specifying your version numbers in your gradle config

Comment: There are two more repositories in the `build.gradle`. And you can find 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT files in [https://repo.spring.io/snapshot](https://repo.spring.io/snapshot). I specified the version '2.6.0-SNAPSHOT' whitin 4 artifacts whose group is 'org.springframework.boot' and re-built. New build scan report is [here](https://gradle.com/s/xle3mupnis5ek), and there's no different.... Could it have been a problem to use a version of SNAPSHOT that could be changed?

Comment: why would you use the snapshot repo when 2.6.0 is out and is stable?

Comment: Well... no persuasive reason . I just selected newest version at the beginning of the development and then never checked framework's update. I'll change it to a stable version, but I doubt it will be a guarantee that the problem will never be reproduced. Since the running build file contains ChannelInputShutdownReadComplete.class in it as I described.